# Creating new column with condition after loc/iloc from the initial df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I created copy of the initial df:

```
Df_p1=df.loc[df[a].str.contains(« P1 », case = true)]

df_n=df_p1.iloc[:,np.r_[4,6,7]].copy
```

Now to the last df I want to add a column that returns 0 or 1:

```
df_n[‘count’]=np.where(df_n[´something´]>0,1,0)
```

And get error: method object is not subscriptable

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your program you forgot to call the `copy` you should change it like `copy()` to call it. `copy` is a method not an attribute.

```
df_n=df_p1.iloc[:,np.r_[4,6,7]].copy()
```